# CSV splitting causes errors

Tags: powershell, csv, locking, export-to-csv

Could you please help me with an issue described below?

I wrote a script in PS which tries to split large CSV file (30 000 rows / 6MB) into smaller ones. New files are named as a mix of 1st and 2nd column content. If file already exists, script only appends new lines.

Main CSV file example:

```
Site;OS.Type;Hostname;IP address
Amsterdam;Server;AMS_SRVDEV01;10.10.10.12
Warsaw;Workstation;WAR-L4D6;10.10.20.22
Ankara;Workstation;AN-D5G36;10.10.13.22
Warsaw;Workstation;WAR-SRVTST02;10.10.20.33
Amsterdam;Server;LON-SRV545;10.10.10.244
```

PowerShell Version: *5.1.17134.858*

```bsh
function Csv-Splitter {
    $fileName = Read-Host "Pass file name to process: "

    $FileToProcess = Import-Csv "$fileName.csv" -Delimiter ';'
    $MyList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]                                         

    foreach ($row in $FileToProcess) {
        if ("$($row.'OS.Type')-$($row.Site)" -notin $MyList) {
            $MyList.Add("$($row.'OS.Type')-$($row.Site)")
            $row | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Append -NoTypeInformation "$($row.'OS.Type')-$($row.Site).csv"
        }
        else {
            $row | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Append -NoTypeInformation "$($row.'OS.Type')-$($row.Site).csv"
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, code works fine, however it generates some errors from time to time when it process through the loop. This causes lack of some rows in new files - number of missing rows equals to amount of errors:

> Export-Csv : The process cannot access the file 'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.csv' because 
>   it is being used by another process.

Comment: file writes take time. my _guess_ is that your loop is getting to the next write before the previous one is finished. the solution [and a fairly big speed-up] is to save your data to a $var for each type & then save each entire collection to a file after the loop has completed. ///// also, you might want to stop repeating the `"$($row.'OS.Type')-$($row.Site)"` and save it to a temp $Var for repeated use. evaluating that string multiple times for each row may slow things down a tad.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Good tips re speed-up, but `Export-Csv` should be synchronous, so the code in the question doesn't explain the problem. Try the following - I have yet to see it fail (and don't expect it to): `$co = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }; ri -ea ignore t.csv; foreach ($i in 1..1e3) { $co | Export-Csv -append t.csv -NoTypeInformation }`. @ArPy, could there be an unrelated process accessing the files while they're being written?

Comment: @mklement0 - yep, it seems unlikely ... but was all i could think of at the time. [*blush*] now that you mention it, i wonder if the OPs anti-virus is scanning the files at just the wrong time ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey / mklement0 - you right... It was Mcafee On Access Scan module accessing each, newly created file. OAS was scanning those files in meantime when the next loop tried to append a new data. Thanks for help!

Comment: @ArPy - thank you for the "why" of it all. would you please either add that as an answer OR add it as a note to your Original Post?

Comment: ArPy: @Lee is right; I'd say this deserves a proper answer. I'm frankly baffled that antivirus software could cause such insidious failures.

Comment: @mklement0 Frankly, I'm not. AV software (regardless of vendor) is notorious for causing all kinds of performance (and security) issues.

Comment: Thank you, @Arpy. No, accepting is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Export-Csv` is *synchronous*** - by the time it returns, the output file has already been closed - so **the code in the question does *not* explain the problem**.

As you've since confirmed in a comment, based on a suggestion by [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey), **the culprit was the AV (anti-virus) Mcafee On-Access Scan module**, which accessed each newly created file behind the scenes, thereby *locking it temporarily*, causing `Export-Csv` to fail intermittently.

The **problem should go away if all output files can be fully created with a *single* `Export-Csv` call each**, after the loop, as also suggested by Lee. This is **preferable for performance anyway**, but assumes that the entire CSV file fits into memory *as a whole*.

Here's a `Group-Object`-based solution that uses a single pipeline to implement write-each-output-file-in-full functionality:

```
function Csv-Splitter {

  $fileName = Read-Host "Pass file name to process: "

  Import-Csv "$fileName.csv" -Delimiter ';' | 
    Group-Object { $_.'OS.Type' + '_' + $_.Site + '.csv' } |
      ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $_.Name }

}
```

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58842660/45375) shows alternative solutions that eliminate interference from the AV software.

Answer (score 0):

Source of the issue was McAfee On-Access Scan which was scanning every file created. There are 3 ways to bypass the problem:

- a) temporarily disable the whole AV / OAS module.
- b) add powershell.exe to the OAS policies as a Low Risk process
- c) collect all data in memory and create all files with Export-CSV, as a last step, as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58807164/45375).

Comment: Thanks for adding that. (b) sounds a bit problematic, given that `powershell.exe` is an open-ended execution engine.